# How to disable sprite and its children?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite, visibility

Obviously `visible = false;` wont affect the children's visible property except that they are actually not visible. What technique can I use to disable the parent sprite and its children and its children's children etc. ?

- **disable** a sprite with **all** its children
- **enable** a sprite with **all** its children
- **not** remove it from stage
- while parent and children are disabled **block their events**

*P.s.: It seems that this feature is missing in ActionScript 3.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of the visible property.

---

According to Adobe, Visible determines:

> Whether or not the display object is visible. Display objects that are not visible are disabled. For example, if visible=false for an InteractiveObject instance, it cannot be clicked.

This does not mean that it will prevent other event handlers such as `Event.ENTER_FRAME` from firing. If you are relying on `visible` to disable elements, you must also verify that this value is in fact `true` before firing an event from that display object.

---

> Well this doesn't work although the parent sprite is not visible the children are not drawn the value of this property remains true.
>
> ...
>
> I can't check easily if children are disabled: if (visible)

If you are setting the parent DisplayObject's visibility to false and expecting it to propagate to all of its children you are wrong. Only the parent's visibility flag will remain false. You should instead verify visibility of a child by checking its parent like so:

```
if(parent.visible) {
    //perform logic here...
}
```

Comment: What about the children's children ? I have a big tree of sprites. I'm setting visibility only on big events that are very rare and I check it pretty much on every frame. Going `if (parent.parent.parent.parent.visible)` is not the way I want to go since I also have to check parent existence.

Comment: Perhaps you would want to consider removing the Listener for that particular object in that instance. You can make it as simple or complex as you wish. The bottom line is that the visible flag is probably not going to cut it and you will most likely need to have a custom class (with methods that enable and disable) that extends the display object you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To get all children's children, you can use this:

```
function getAllChildChilds(source : DisplayObjectContainer) : Array {
var returnArr:Array = [];
getAllChildChildsIntern(source, returnArr, new int(), new int());
return returnArr;

function getAllChildChildsIntern(container : DisplayObjectContainer, childArr : Array, i : int, j : int) : void {
    j = container.numChildren;
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        var child : * = container.getChildAt(i);
        if (child is DisplayObjectContainer) {
            var mc : DisplayObjectContainer= child;
            childArr.push(mc);
            getAllChildChildsIntern(mc, childArr, new int(), new int());
        }
    }
}}
```

usage:
getAllChildChilds(mc); //returns an array with all children and children's children of mc. (mc itself is not in the array)

Everything else was answered by Andreas.

Comment: And no one is making a full answer ?